# Access Activity in Fragment when clicking on side menu item

Tags: android

I am trying to build a side menu. How can I show an Activity in a Fragment when the user clicks on a side menu item? It's showing the Fragment when the user clicks on a side menu item. But it's not showing the Activity.

Comment: you have to provide some information. What have you tried so far? What errors have you faced?
Provide some code an extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate Activities inside a Fragment using LocalActivityManager, but it was deprecated in API 13 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html).

See this example if you really want to do this instead of just using fragments as they were intended: http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/many-activity-inside-fragment-in-android.html